# "OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" error

Tags: 14.04, python, django, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtualenv environment but I am encountered by this error:

```
user@mylaptop:~$ virtualenv -p ~/Public/Programming/project1/
Running virtualenv with interpreter /home/user/Public/Programming/Project1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==12.0.6', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 784, in main
    popen = subprocess.Popen([interpreter, file] + sys.argv[1:], env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

*What should I do?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified the Python interpreter to use to create your virtual environment in `~/Public/Programming/project1/` directory.

From `man virtualenv`:

```
-p PYTHON_EXE,--python=PYTHON_EXE
The Python interpreter to use to create the new environment.
```

The `-p` option expects the next argument to be the python interpreter on which the new environment would be based. But you missed that argument and `virtualenv` thinks you want to base your environment on `~/Public/Programming/project1/` interpreter. But there is no interpreter available there, and hence you get that `OSError`.

If you want to use Python 2.7, the correct command would be:

```
virtualenv -p python2.7 ~/Public/Programming/project1/
```

and for Python 3.4, it would be:

```
virtualenv -p python3.4 ~/Public/Programming/project1/
```